# Preloading data in Tensorflow with shared layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have Tensorflow code for multi-task learning (one input, several outputs, similar to this: https://jg8610.github.io/Multi-Task/). For further explanation see below. The code works, but is slow as there's a lot of overhead from reading data in Python and feeding it to the GPU (with the tf.Session's `feed_dict`).

So my plan is now to preload the data according to https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#preloaded_data [storing it in a `tf.constant` and using TF's queuing system]. This raises some problems, of which the most central for now seems to be:

- If I preload the different task data into different tensors, I no longer have a task-generic `X_in`. That means that when declaring the shared layer, I now need to make a decision whether to connect it to `X_input_task_A` or `X_input_task_B`, and obviously that's not going to result in a *shared* layer.

**My question**

Would you have any idea how to solve this problem, i.e. to define shared layers with task-specific tensors, and then training by alternating between tasks? How would you alternatively call the different optimizer operations?

**Further explanation on the Multi-task learning paradigm**

For background, what the mentioned blog post (as well as my code so far) does is to define a placeholder `X_in` plus a shared layer that consumes that input op. Then, for each task we want to learn, we have different projections and loss functions that use task-specific placeholders `y_task`, and training happens by alternately running `session.run(optimizer_task, feed_dict={X_in: X_batch_task, y_task: y_batch_task})`, where `optimizer_task` is some task-specific optimizer. This is basically what my code does now - it works but is slow because I need to feed the data:

```
# PLACEHOLDERS
X_in = tf.placeholder([batch_size, 100])
y_task_a = tf.placeholder([batch_size, 4])  # 4 output classes
y_task_b = tf.placeholder([batch_size, 2])  # 2 output classes

# SHARED LAYER
W = tf.get_variable("W", [100, 50])  
shared_layer = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X_in, W))

# TASK-SPECIFIC OUTPUTS
W_task_a = tf.get_variable("Wa", [50, 4])
W_task_b = tf.get_variable("Wb", [50, 2])
pred_task_a = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(shared_layer, W_task_a))
pred_task_b = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(shared_layer, W_task_b))

# TASK-SPECIFIC LOSSES AND OPTIMIZERS
loss_task_a = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred_task_a, labels=y_task_a)
loss_task_b = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred_task_b, labels=y_task_b)
optimizer_a = ...(loss_task_a)
optimizer_b = ...(loss_task_b)

# TRAINING
with tf.Session() as sess:
  for i in range(ITERS):
    # ALTERNATE BETWEEN TASKS, GET BATCH FROM DATA PER TASK AND TRAIN
    X_a, y_a = data_task_a.get_batch()
    X_b, y_b = data_task_b.get_batch()
    sess.run(optimizer_a, feed_dict={X_in: X_a, y_task_a: y_a})
    sess.run(optimizer_b, feed_dict={X_in: X_b, y_task_b: y_b})
```